# Can't access the key proper value

Tags: javascript, html, object

i am doing something in which i create an html img element in javascript then i want that img width and height but when i try console log img width and height its return 0 but when i console log img whole object its showing proper value like this

```
let img = document.createElement("img")
img.src = "./img/img1.png"
console.log(img)
console.log(img.width)
console.log(img.height)
```

Here first console shows an html element which have both height and width with a different value like width is 580 and height is 100 but in second and third it shows 0 for width and for height too.

However, there is another thing when i try to run this script in with html file in script tag it run perfectly fine just like i wanted.

addition detail :
my html file is normal html boiler plat and i am using script type 'text/javascript'

Answer (score 3):

width/height wont be known until the image has loaded, so you should use the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event if you want width/height

```js
let img = document.createElement("img")
img.onload = () => {
  console.log('works %sx%s', img.width, img.height)
}
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300"

console.log('wont work %sx%s', img.width, img.height)
```

Comment: Man I am idiot I spend more then half an hour to figure out is it normal or some bug by my and try to do it in some other way thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can use naturalHeight and naturalWidth instead of height and width
it is working perfectly for me  hope it is works for you also after pageload

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/colourful-illustration-programmer-working_23-2148281410.jpg?w=740&t=st=1649947934~exp=1649948534~hmac=1c14d627b3208ef3367c0cad486f2a20b72cacec394f8371a79b1a2aeb07ad45";
window.onload = function exampleFunction() {
  console.log(img);
  console.log(img.naturalHeight);
  console.log(img.naturalWidth);
  console.log("it is a freepik dummy image for testing");
  // Function to be executed
}
```